# Как работать со связями Active Record в Yii2 (populateRelation, link и т.п.)?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

В июне 2014 года на Хабрахабре была [статья с описанием работы с связями Active Record в Yii2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/226103/). Через месяц статья исчезла, но осталась в многочисленных копиях, например [здесь](http://newsroller.ru/11-habrahabr/35-it/7588-yii2-svyazi-active-record/).

Как и некоторые другие разработчики, (см. [здесь](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=18507) и [здесь](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18565)) я попытался разобраться в примере, который приводит автор этой статьи. И вот уже несколько дней меня не покидает ощущение, что чего-то в той статье не хватает.

Нормального описания подхода я так и не нашел (разве что наметки [здесь](http://sllite.ru/2014/11/yii2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-6-%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/)). Зачитал официальное руководство до дыр, но [приемы записи связанны моделей в БД описаны очень скупо](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations), чтение [документации по Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html) тоже не особо помогло.

И все-таки хочется разобраться с этим кодом, с этим подходом, понять, какие возможности заложены в фреймворк, чтобы не городить огород поверх имеющегося.

**Код из статьи**

*Модель*

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
    // Будем использовать транзакции при указанных сценариях
    public function transactions()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => self::OP_INSERT | self::OP_UPDATE,
        ];
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
            ->viaTable('post_tag', ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->populateRelation('tags', $tags);
        $this->tags_count = count($tags);
    }

    // Сеттер для получения тегов из строки, разделенных запятой
    public function setTagsString($value)
    {
        $tags = [];

        foreach (explode(',' $value) as $name) {
             $tag = new Tag();
             $tag->name = $name;
             $tags[] = $tag;
        }

        $this->setTags($tags);
    }

    public function getCover()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::className(), ['id' => 'cover_id']);
    }

    public function setCover($cover)
    {
        $this->populateRelation('cover', $cover);
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function setImages($images)
    {
        $this->populateRelation('images', $images);

        if (!$this->isRelationPopulated('cover') && !$this->getCover()->one()) {
            $this->setCover(reset($images));
        }
    }

    public function loadUploadedImages()
    {
           $images = [];

           foreach (UploadedFile::getInstances(new Image(), 'image') as $file) {
                $image = new Image();
                $image->name = $file->name;
                $images[] = $image;
           }

           $this->setImages($images);
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            return false;
        }

       // В beforeSave мы сохраняем связанные модели
       // которые нужно сохранить до основной, т.е. нужны их ИД
       // Не волнуйтесь о транзакции т.к. мы настроили,
       // она будет начата при вызове метода `insert()` и `update()`

       // Получаем все связанные модели, те что загружены или установлены
       $relatedRecords = $this->getRelatedRecords();

       if (isset($relatedRecords['cover'])) {
           $this->link('cover', $relatedRecords['cover']);
       }

       return true;
    }

    public function afterSave($insert)
    {

       // В afterSave мы сохраняем связанные модели
       // которые нужно сохранять после основной модели, т.к. нужен ее ИД

       // Получаем все связанные модели, те что загружены или установлены
       $relatedRecords = $this->getRelatedRecords();

       if (isset($relatedRecords['tags'])) {
           foreach ($relatedRecords['tags'] as $tag) {
               $this->link('tags', $tag);
           }
       }

       if (isset($relatedRecords['images'])) {
           foreach ($relatedRecords['images'] as $image) {
               $this->link('images', $image);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

*Контроллер*

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $post = new Post();

        if ($post->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            // Сохраняем загруженные файлы
            $post->loadUploadedImages();

            if ($post->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $post->id]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'post' => $post,
        ]);
     }
}
```

Вопросы по коду:

1. Как работают сеттеры в этом примере? Откуда берутся значения, передаваемые сеттерам ($tags, $cover, $images...)?
2. В какой момент пишутся данные из связанных моделей (теги, изображения, главное изображение) в базу данных?
3. Чего не хватает в этом коде, чтобы он заработал?

Отдельно хотелось бы попросить ссылок на репозитории серьезных проектов, использующих Yii2. Очень хочется посмотреть на лучшие практики в реальных сложных проектах.

Comment: Привел полностью рабочий пример данного кода. Единственное поменял поле cover в таблице постов на флаг is_cover в таблице изображений. Не хорошо когда у таблиц нет внешних ключей.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Overview

В контроллере:

`$post->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` выполняет загрузку модели. `Yii::$app->request->post()` возвращает массив, вида `['MyFormName[key]' => 'value]`. В `load` для каждого свойства модели с именем `key` устанавливается значение, если для них существуют правила валидации `rules` и данное поле прописано в сценарии.

В модели:

`getTags` это релейшен. Служит для связей ActiveRecord моделей. `setTags` хоть и выглядит как сеттер (сеттер, это функция вызываемая при обращении к несуществующему свойству), но в данном случае это просто функция. Она сохраняет связанную модель с помощью `populateRelation` и увеличивает текущий счетчик `$this->tags_count`. К слову о проблеме публичных свойств, счетчик можно увеличить напрямую, без вызова метод `setTags`.

---

> Как работают сеттеры в этом примере? Откуда берутся значения, передаваемые сеттерам ($tags, $cover, $images...)?

`setCover`, `setTags`, `setImages` вызываются внутри модели c обычной передачей параметров. Полагаю, они должны быть приватными и не вызываться из клиентского кода (контроллера).

> В какой момент пишутся данные из связанных моделей (теги, изображения, главное изображение) в базу данных?

В момент вызова `populateRelation` в модели происходит заполнение связанного релейшена. Сохранение происходит в контроллере в момент `save` модели.

> Чего не хватает в этом коде, чтобы он заработал?

Написать всё заново, используя этот код только в качестве примера. Вам ведь нужен опыт, и это избавит вас от необходимости думать о функциях вроде `setTagsString`, которые нигде не используются и вносят только путаницу. Также будет понятно что для работы метода `getRelatedRecords` у вас должны быть заполнены таблицы `images` и `tags`.

Я рекомендую взять [этот раздел документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html) и по очереди пройтись по каждым функциям. Это долго, по всем я сам ещё не прошелся, но это позволит получить максимально полное представление о возможностях ActiveRecord фреймворка, не копаясь в коде сомнительного качества.

---

## Update: Пример рабочего кода данного примера.

Несмотря на то что это просто быстрый рефакторинг готов в кодревью и вопросам в комментариях.

Миграция:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m151122_155133_create_tables extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $tableOptions = null;
        if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
            $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
        }

        $this->createTable('{{%post}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'message' => $this->text(),
            'tags_count' => $this->integer(2)->notNull()->defaultValue(0)
        ], $tableOptions);

        $this->createTable('{{%tag}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string(32)->notNull(),
            'UNIQUE INDEX `UNQ_tag__name` (`name`)',
        ], $tableOptions);

        $this->batchInsert('{{%tag}}', ['name'], [
            ['tag1'],
            ['tag2'],
        ]);

        $this->createTable('{{%post_tag}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'post_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
            'tag_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
            'FOREIGN KEY `FK_post_tag__post_id` (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
                ON UPDATE RESTRICT
                ON DELETE RESTRICT',
            'FOREIGN KEY `FK_post_tag__tag_id` (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id)
                ON UPDATE RESTRICT
                ON DELETE RESTRICT',
        ], $tableOptions);

        $this->createTable('{{%post_image}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'post_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
            'image' => $this->string(128)->notNull(),
            'is_cover' => $this->boolean()->defaultValue(0),
            'FOREIGN KEY `FK_post_image__post_id` (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
                ON UPDATE RESTRICT
                ON DELETE RESTRICT',
        ], $tableOptions);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('{{%post_image}}');
        $this->dropTable('{{%post_tag}}');
        $this->dropTable('{{%tag}}');
        $this->dropTable('{{%post}}');
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use frontend\models\CreatePostForm;
use frontend\models\Post;
use frontend\models\PostSearch;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Exception;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * PostController implements the CRUD actions for Post model.
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Post models.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PostSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Post model.
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Post model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CreatePostForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if (!$model->createNewPost()) {
                throw new Exception('Failed to save CreatePostForm');
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Post model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return Post the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Post::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Представление `index.php`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\models\PostSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Posts';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="post-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Post', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'message:ntext',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Представление `create.php`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Post */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$this->title = 'Create Post';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Posts', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="post-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="post-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'tagString')->input('text') ?>
        <?= $form->field((new \frontend\models\PostImage()), 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Представление `view.php`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Post */

$this->title = $model->id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Posts', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="post-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'message:ntext',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Модель `CreatePostForm`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class CreatePostForm extends Post
{
    /**
     * Храним тут строку. Приватная потому что нам нужен сеттер, и мы за компанию прописываем геттер чтобы нельзя было писать напрямую в свойство, минуя сеттер.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $_tagString;

    /**
     * Load отработает только для тех полей для которых прописаны правила валидации.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge([
            ['tagString', 'string']
        ], parent::rules());
    }

    /**
     * Стараемся в контроллере не работать напрямую с ActiveRecord.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function createNewPost()
    {
        $this->loadUploadedImages();

        return $this->save();
    }

    /**
     * Просто получаем теги, которые ввел пользователь на форме
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTagString()
    {
        return $this->_tagString;
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем картинки. Тут только запись названий в бд, запись файлов не производится.
     *
     * @see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html
     */
    private function loadUploadedImages()
    {
        $images = [];

        foreach (UploadedFile::getInstances(new PostImage(), 'image') as $file) {
            $image = new PostImage();
            $image->image = $file->name;
            $images[] = $image;
        }

        $this->setImages($images);
    }

    /**
     * Сохряняем связи картинок и для первой картинки устанавливаем флаг is_cover. Тут в примере только создание, но если бы было обновление вызов setCover бы
     * не произошел.
     *
     * @param PostImage[] $images
     */
    private function setImages($images)
    {
        $this->populateRelation('images', $images);

        if (!$this->isRelationPopulated('cover') && !$this->getCover()->one()) {
            $this->setCover(reset($images));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем главную картинку поста.
     *
     * @param PostImage $cover
     */
    private function setCover($cover)
    {
        $cover->is_cover = true;
        $this->populateRelation('cover', $cover);
    }

    /**
     * Записываем строчку тегов, полученную от пользователя в связанную таблицу.
     *
     * @param string $tagString
     */
    public function setTagString($tagString)
    {
        $this->_tagString = $tagString;

        $this->saveTagsToRelation();
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем теги в связанной таблице и увеличиваем счетчик
     */
    private function saveTagsToRelation()
    {
        $tags = [];

        /**
         * Пример с viaTable в релейшене Post::getTags подразумевал что теги только выбираются, но не создаются.
         */
        foreach (explode(',', $this->_tagString) as $name) {
            $tag = Tag::find()->where(['name' => trim($name)])->one();
            if (!$tag) {
                continue;
            }

            $tags[] = $tag;
        }

        $this->populateRelation('tags', $tags);
        $this->tags_count = count($tags);
    }
}
```

Модель `Post`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "post".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $message
 * @property integer $tags_count
 *
 * @property PostImage $image
 * @property Tag[] $tags
 */
class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'post';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['tags_count', 'integer'],
            [['message'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'message' => 'Message',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function transactions()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => self::OP_INSERT | self::OP_UPDATE,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCover()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PostImage::className(), ['post_id' => 'id'])
            ->andWhere(['is_cover' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostImage::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
            ->viaTable('post_tag', ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * В afterSave мы сохраняем связанные модели, которые нужно сохранять после основной модели, т.к. нужен ее ИД.
     *
     * @param bool $true
     * @param array $changedAttributes
     */
    public function afterSave($true, $changedAttributes)
    {
        $relatedRecords = $this->getRelatedRecords();

        if (isset($relatedRecords['cover'])) {
            $this->link('cover', $relatedRecords['cover']);
        }

        if (isset($relatedRecords['tags'])) {
            foreach ($relatedRecords['tags'] as $tag) {
                $this->link('tags', $tag);
            }
        }

        if (isset($relatedRecords['images'])) {
            foreach ($relatedRecords['images'] as $image) {
                $this->link('images', $image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Модель `PostImage`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "post_image".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $post_id
 * @property string $image
 * @property integer $is_cover
 *
 * @property Post $post
 */
class PostImage extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'post_image';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['post_id', 'image'], 'required'],
            [['post_id', 'is_cover'], 'integer'],
            [['image'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            [['post_id'], 'unique'],
            [['post_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Post::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['post_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'post_id' => 'Post ID',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'is_cover' => 'Is Cover',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Post::className(), ['id' => 'post_id']);
    }
}
```

Модель `PostTag`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "post_tag".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $post_id
 * @property integer $tag_id
 *
 * @property Post $post
 * @property Tag $post0
 */
class PostTag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'post_tag';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['post_id', 'tag_id'], 'required'],
            [['post_id', 'tag_id'], 'integer'],
            [['post_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Post::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['post_id' => 'id']],
            [['tag_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Tag::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['tag_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'post_id' => 'Post ID',
            'tag_id' => 'Tag ID',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Post::className(), ['id' => 'post_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPost0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'post_id']);
    }
}
```

Модель `Tag`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tag".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 *
 * @property PostTag[] $postTags
 */
class Tag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['name'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPostTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostTag::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Модель `PostSearch`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\models\Post;

/**
 * PostSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\models\Post`.
 */
class PostSearch extends Post
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['message'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Post::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'message', $this->message]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Вникаю. Вас не затруднит убрать сгенерированные Gii и не особо полезные комментарии типа @inheritdoc? Отвлекают от сути ответа.

Comment: Мысли по поводу (пока немного далеко от сути вопроса, но тем не менее). Модель PostTag не нужна. А модель PostImage явно просит, чтобы ее переименовали. Плюс потенциально: изображения могут относиться не только к статьям, а одно изображение может встречаться в нескольких статьях. Т.е. связь многие-ко-многим.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin Идея таблицы `PostTag` в том чтобы использовать теги `Tag` не только для постов, но и для других сущностей. В рамках данного примера она действительно избыточна, но без неё нельзя было бы показать пример работы `viaTable`. `Postimage` тоже можно сделать повторно используемой для других сущностей, хотя лично я бы дождался возникновения дублирования. Аватарки, фотки и картинки к постам хоть и `Images`, но хранение и работа с ними скорее всего будет вестись по разному. Чуть позже почищу ответ от пустых моделей.

Comment: Не забываем в методе afterSave делать вызов метода наследуемого класса, как указанно в документации 
> When overriding this method, make sure you call the parent implementation so that the event is triggered.

 `public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
 
    //... тут ваш код
}'

Answer (score 3):

> Как работают сеттеры в этом примере? Откуда берутся значения, передаваемые сеттерам ($tags, $cover, $images...)?

Это PHP-магия. В базовом классе переопределены методы `__get` и `__set`, которые преобразуют чтение и запись атрибутов `$foo->bar = $baz->qwe` в вызовы методов `$foo->setBar($baz->getQwe())`. Если магия не нравится, то можно вызывать методы и напрямую.

По сути, это банальные геттеры и сеттеры. В некоторых языках есть свойства (геттеры и сеттеры, объединённые в единую сущность), но PHP их не поддерживает.

> В какой момент пишутся данные из связанных моделей (теги, изображения, главное изображение) в базу данных?

Когда вызывается метод `save` у `ActiveRecord`. В этот момент данные валидируются и, если валидация проходит, то записываются данные этой `ActiveRecord` и всех связанных.

> Чего не хватает в этом коде, чтобы он заработал?

На этот вопрос невозможно ответить, пока вы не скажете, что именно не работает.

Можно посмотреть комментарии, там указан какой-то баг: https://sohabr.net/habr/post/226103/

Судя по всему, популярностью эта статья не пользовалась, поэтому не понимаю желания полагаться на неё при обучении.

> Отдельно хотелось бы попросить ссылок на репозитории серьезных проектов, использующих Yii2. Очень хочется посмотреть на лучшие практики в реальных сложных проектах.

Есть пример [yii2-shop](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop) от одного из авторов фреймворка.

Comment: Я вижу в этом примере то, что хотел бы видеть в своем проекте (тоже несколько связанных моделей и хочется свести к минимуму код в контроллерах). Магия сеттеров и геттеров в PHP мне понятна, мне не понятно, как это работает именно здесь. К сеттеру ведь где-то нужно обратиться, чтоб "магия" сработала.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin Ну вот у вас есть переменная `$post`, вы у неё можете читать и изменять свойства как раз с помощью этих магических методов.

Comment: Oк. Это я понимаю. Вот смотрю я на контроллер и вижу, как грузятся данные из \Yii::$app->request->post()['Post'] в этот самый $post. Тут все понятно. Но вот не уверен, что этого достаточно для того, чтобы связанные модели тоже были заполнены. Особенно интересен в этом отношении метод setTagsString(), который как бы сеттер, но вроде и не сеттер. По крайней мере, в моем случае связанные модели не заполняются. $this->getRelatedRecords() в beforeSeve() и afterSave() ничего не возвращают, собственно, магии не случается.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin Попробуйте походить отладчиком, проверьте, правильно ли работает `setTagsString` и т. п.